# Long File Path Fails to Copy File to New Directory

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this posted under my original post, but thought I would create a new question. I have the below code working that looks at my table in MS Access that has the path + file name and moves it to a new directory; I will also be looking at how to put Folders/Subfolders in the "new" directory based off of the original directory, but am unsure how to accomplish that. It currently works on my test table that has <259 characters in the path, but fails on long path/file names >259.  Thoughts how how this can be addressed?

Appreciate the help.

```
 Sub CopyFilesFromTable2()

 On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

 Dim source As String
 Dim destination As String
 Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
 Dim SQL As String
 Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
 Dim db As DAO.Database



 'Test Table
  SQL = "select * from file_test"

 'Prod Table
 'SQL = "select * from file"

  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set RS = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)

  source = RS!LocalFile
  File = VBA.FileSystem.Dir(source)
  destination = "D:\Temp\Test\"

  With RS

  If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then

  .MoveLast
  .MoveFirst

   While (Not .EOF)

   FSO.CopyFile RS!LocalFile, destination

  .MoveNext

   Wend


   End If

   .Close

   End With


   ExitSub:

   Set RS = Nothing
   'set to nothing
    MsgBox "Done!"

   Exit Sub

    ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err, vbCritical

    Resume ExitSub


   End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation

Comment: All sorts of applications will have problems with files in these long paths, so it is generally best to just avoid it completely.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a problem with long paths here, generally, these are best avoided.

However, with a tiny bit of WinAPI, you can easily avoid the issue.

Implement [`CopyFileExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfileexw):

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function CopyFileExW Lib "Kernel32.DLL" (ByVal lpExistingFileName As LongPtr, ByVal lpNewFileName As LongPtr, ByVal lpProgressRoutine As LongPtr, ByVal lpData As LongPtr, ByRef pbCancel As Boolean, ByVal dwCopyFlags As Long) As Boolean
```

Declare consts:

```
Const COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS = 1&
```

Create a function that calls `CopyFileExW`, and prepends `\\?\` to the path to allow for long paths:

```
Public Function CopyFile(strSource As String, strDestination As String, Optional Overwrite As Boolean = False)
    strSource = "\\?\" & strSource
    strDestination = "\\?\" & strDestination
    Dim flags As Long
    If Not Overwrite Then
        flags = COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS
    End If
    Dim res As Boolean
    res = CopyFileExW(StrPtr(strSource), StrPtr(strDestination), 0, 0, ByVal 0, flags)
    If res = False Then
        Err.Raise -5000, Description:="Copy file failed, error code " & Err.LastDllError
    End If
End Function
```

And use that function, instead of `RS!LocalFile, destination`:

```
'CopyFile file needs the full path, so we append the filename
CopyFile RS!LocalFile, Destination & Right(RS!LocalFile, InStr(strReverse("RS!LocalFile"), "\") - 1)
```

Comment: @ Erik A, thanks for your help. Folks love to use long file names that causes these types of issues:) 

I've added the Public Declare/Consts/and replaced RS!LocalFile, Destination with the function line; it's running, and completes, but doesn't move the files. Is there an additional Reference that I need to enable?

Comment: I uncommented my ErrorHandler and am getting a Invalid procedure call or argument message. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not really, you could wrap the args in `CStr` or print the file names to make sure your filenames are valid, but the function works for me.